# Looking to read the .text of cells into an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, range

I'm building a simple report compare macro in Excel VBA to compare all sorts of different reports in our system.  Since it's so much faster I'm pulling both spreadsheets into arrays and running a compare on them then pasting the results into a different workbook.

The issue is that both spreadsheets have long underlying values in some cells (interest rates and things like 3.27823202), but all I care about is the displayed value in the cell (3.28).  I know I can easily pull the .values into an array with

```
Dim ReportParams() as variant
Dim SH1 as Worksheet
set SH1= activeworkbook.sheets("Sheet1")
ReportParams= SH1.range(cells(1,1),cells(5,5)).Value
```

But when I attempt the same using .Text instead of .Value it gives me a Run-Time error '13': Type Mismatch.

Is there any effecient way to bring in all the visible values for the cells into an array?

Comment: You will need to loop and put the `.Text` in one at a time.

Comment: If the all are rounded the same then you can load the array at once, then loop through the array and round the number.  It will be a little quicker than looping the range.

Comment: Just convert each cell with Cstr as you add it to the array.  you can always Format as well with Format(Cell.value, "0.00") if you only want 2 significant digits.

Comment: Thanks for the help all (except Axel, but I fixed the code so you can stop complaining), sadly the rounding won't work since the columns are not all formatted the same.  some are text, some are numbers rounded to zero decimals, some are numbers rounded to 2 or 3 decimal places.

And since I'm trying to keep it report neutral I don't want to have to define it by each column if possible.  Maybe I can pull in the format settings and get the value from that then round the column once I've read it into the array.